# On Tap of UILabel (gesture recogniser) finding nil in tableview prototype cell for one cell and its working fine for another two cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement UITapGestureRecognizer, Idea is that on tap of label I will get a pop up displaying the number to make call and it should come up with pop up alert saying call or cancel!!

Code I've written worked for me in 3 to 4 places but I am stuck at one point
In this screen I have a tableview with prototype cells grouped type here, please check this Image:

[Link For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W039l.png)

**Third Cell**

Now If I am Tapping **065668982** I have **canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://065668982" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"** which actually works on iPhone not on simulator and it pulls to call which is working fine.

**Second Cell**

If I am Tapping **065454858** I have **canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://065668982" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"** which actually works on iPhone not on simulator and it pulls to call which is working fine.

**first Cell**

But for first one it never works and end up with **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

NOTE : I am Getting phone Number from an API and append the data in view controller to UITableViewCell.

I Hope I make sense, Thanks in advance for any help also if I am not clear please comment below

**Here is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class XyzTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UILabel!
    var touchContact : String = ""

   var myCell: MyCellData! {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI()
    {
        touchContact = vicarCell.phone_no

        //Tap Gesture
        tapGestureAddonView()
    }
    
    //MARK:- Tap to Call and Open Email
    func tapGestureAddonView(){
        
        let contacttap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:("contactTapped"))
        contacttap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        phoneNumber!.userInteractionEnabled = true
        phoneNumber!.addGestureRecognizer(contacttap)
        
        
    }
    
    func contactTapped() {
        // do something cool here
        
        print("contactTapped")
        print(touchContact)
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(self.touchContact)")!){
            
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(self.touchContact)")!)
        }
        else{
            //showAlert("Info",message: "Your device could not called" ,owner: self)
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you don't implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate instead of adding gesture to tableview cell ?

Comment: So I tried `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` earlier and it works fine if I have just one label, but for multiple label (which has multiple Phone numbers and email ID's) I have to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` to redirect to Phone call or to Write email (I am using this `MFMailComposeViewController` for email).

Answer (score 1):

The issues: 1) you should add gesture only once 2) you should check `NSURL` for nil. Let me assume that you use storyboard and improve your code a bit

```
class XyzTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UILabel!
    var touchContact : String = ""

    var myCell: MyCellData! {didSet {self.updateUI()}}

    func updateUI() {
        touchContact = myCell.phone_no // did you mean myCell instead vicarCell?
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        tapGestureAddonView()
    }

    func tapGestureAddonView(){
        let contacttap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(contactTapped))
        contacttap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        phoneNumber!.userInteractionEnabled = true
        phoneNumber!.addGestureRecognizer(contacttap)
    }

    func contactTapped() {
        print("contactTapped")
        print(touchContact)
        if touchContact.isEmpty {return}
        guard let url = NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(touchContact)") else {
            print("url string invalid")
            return
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url){
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            } else{
                //showAlert("Info",message: "Your device could not called" ,owner: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Of for making correction in code I appreciate your time you spend on my code, But I already did this exception handling my question is why Its taking that thing **nil** Here is something I debug it: 1) I clicked on last number (which is third cell in table view) I got contactTapped
065668982
2016-06-29 15:27:45.269 ajc[18065:458502] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://065668982" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"

Comment: similalry it works for 2nd row also  When I tap on first cell I got:     contactTapped 
065674876 
url string invalid .. **here If I have Number in string why its coming in this exception**

Comment: I ran it and showing you logs:  contactTapped
065668982
2016-06-29 15:27:45.269 ajc[18065:458502] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://065668982" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"
contactTapped
065454858
2016-06-29 15:27:47.678 ajc[18065:458502] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "telprompt://065454858" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"
contactTapped 
065674876 
url string invalid ... I Hope this is useful for you !!!

Comment: @Sunil seems like your string with 065674876 number contains also some space characters at start or at end of number.

Comment: I wrote **touchContact = touchContact.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")** still Same thing, No progress.

Comment: @Sunil crash place is obvious. Do something, help us to find it! `touchContact` may contain other invalid hidden symbols, '\n' for example. Share your project or give us fully relevant information please; we don't see how cells are configure.

Comment: I checked API's also anyways I end up doing hardcoded number on label's coz don wanna stuck it here for longer, Between Thanks Buddy **@Shadow**  For all your value able answers and time !!